# Substring Array is null

Tags: arrays, substring

```
    String[] s = new String [args[0].length()];
    int[] L = new int [args[0].length()];

    System.out.println(s.length);

    for ( int i = s.length; i == 0; i--){
        s[s.length-i] = args[0].substring(i,i+1);
```

The Problem is that the loop doenst write anything and the result of s[i] is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is always false (i==0)

use:

```
for ( int i = s.length; i > 0; i--){
```